# Failed to Install CocoaPods in Unity LTS 2017.4.40f1 and Appodeal on mac os x Mojave 10.14.5

Tags: ruby, macos, unity-game-engine, appodeal

I am using Appodeals ads integration on Unity LTS 2017.4.40f1 on mac os x Mojave 10.14.5.

The integration fails with an error in the Unity iOS Resolver window:

```
Installing CocoaPods...
gem install cocoapods --user-install
WARNING: You don't have /Users/developer/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in your PATH. 
gem executables will not run
ERROR: Error installing cocoapods:
zeitwerk requires Ruby version >= 2.5
```

Also in the unity console I get this error: 
"Failed to Install CocoaPods for the current user."

**I have tried many things and all failed.**

1. I have tried updating my ruby with brew but Unity does not recognize it.
   When I type in terminal: **ruby -v**
   I get: **ruby 2.5.0p0 (2017-12-25 revision 61468) [x86_64-darwin18]**
   Unity still can't see the new Ruby
2. I tried to install cocoapods manually many times, it worked well but it's still not recognizable by Unity/Appodeal.
3. I tried to go with a terminal to the Unity project directory and install cocoapods with --user-install switch, and still nothing changed
4. I tried adding Ruby paths to $PATH, but nothing changes.
5. I tried multiple Ruby versions, including 2.3.0, 2.5.0 and 2.7.0
6. I restarted the system and Unity many times, and also tried reimporting the plugin
7. Tried multiple solutions from web, but nothing works.

My question is: how to resolve this problem so Appodeal works on my Unity 2017?
Extra question: why seemingly nothing works, why even with cocoapods installed Unity Appodeal still complains?

Comment: How did you add ruby to your path?

Comment: @BugFinder sudo nano /etc/paths and verified with echo $PATH or something like that

Answer (score 0):

There is a flag that needs to be added `--with-libyaml-dir=$(brew --prefix libyaml) --with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl`. Homebrew runs in the system context and so can't update ~/Library.

Steps are on this markdown: https://gist.github.com/RedenticDev/2c71869492ba2740a3725216898c522a

I had the same issue, though with different software versions. Unity 2020.3 on Big Sur (Mac OS 11).

Your other easier option might be to upgrade your Mac OS and then the version of Ruby will also be implicitly upgraded as well.