# Unity build iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

I never had this problem before.
I haven't built anything in about half a year, i used firebase the same way before and build worked good in unity and Xcode too.

Now I try make new app and if I add Firebase (newest version) then I can't build.
But i used firebase for a long time and it worked properly last year..

```
iOS framework addition failed due to a CocoaPods installation failure. This will will likely result in an non-functional Xcode project.

After the failure, "pod repo update" was executed and succeeded. "pod install" was then attempted again, and still failed. This may be due to a broken CocoaPods installation. See: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html for potential solutions.

pod install output:

Analyzing dependencies
[!] `FirebaseAnalytics` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.10.0`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.8.4`.





pod repo update output:

Updating spec repo `cocoapods`
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/mac/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods fetch origin --progress
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/mac/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
  master
  $ /usr/bin/git -C /Users/mac/.cocoapods/repos/cocoapods reset --hard origin/master
  HEAD is now at b1f7c79b7757 [Add] TensorFlowLiteSelectTfOps 0.0.1-nightly.20220607
Updating spec repo `trunk`

CocoaPods 1.11.3 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods`

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.11.3



  remote: Enumerating objects: 1694, done.        
  remote: Counting objects:   0% (1/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:   1% (17/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:   2% (34/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:   3% (51/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:   4% (68/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:   5% (85/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:   6% (102/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:   7% (119/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:   8% (136/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:   9% (153/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  10% (170/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  11% (187/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  12% (204/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  13% (221/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  14% (238/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  15% (255/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  16% (272/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  17% (288/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  18% (305/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  19% (322/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  20% (339/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  21% (356/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  22% (373/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  23% (390/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  24% (407/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  25% (424/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  26% (441/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  27% (458/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  28% (475/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  29% (492/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  30% (509/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  31% (526/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  32% (543/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  33% (560/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  34% (576/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  35% (593/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  36% (610/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  37% (627/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  38% (644/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  39% (661/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  40% (678/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  41% (695/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  42% (712/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  43% (729/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  44% (746/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  45% (763/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  46% (780/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  47% (797/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  48% (814/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  49% (831/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  50% (847/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  51% (864/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  52% (881/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  53% (898/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  54% (915/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  55% (932/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  56% (949/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  57% (966/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  58% (983/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  59% (1000/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  60% (1017/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  61% (1034/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  62% (1051/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  63% (1068/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  64% (1085/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  65% (1102/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  66% (1119/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  67% (1135/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  68% (1152/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  69% (1169/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  70% (1186/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  71% (1203/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  72% (1220/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  73% (1237/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  74% (1254/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  75% (1271/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  76% (1288/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  77% (1305/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  78% (1322/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  79% (1339/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  80% (1356/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  81% (1373/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  82% (1390/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  83% (1407/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  84% (1423/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  85% (1440/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  86% (1457/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  87% (1474/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  88% (1491/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  89% (1508/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  90% (1525/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  91% (1542/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  92% (1559/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  93% (1576/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  94% (1593/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  95% (1610/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  96% (1627/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  97% (1644/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  98% (1661/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects:  99% (1678/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects: 100% (1694/1694)        
  remote: Counting objects: 100% (1694/1694), done.        
  remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   1% (10/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   2% (19/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   3% (29/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   4% (38/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   5% (48/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   6% (57/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   7% (67/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   8% (76/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:   9% (85/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  10% (95/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  11% (104/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  12% (114/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  13% (123/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  14% (133/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  15% (142/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  16% (152/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  17% (161/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  18% (170/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  19% (180/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  20% (189/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  21% (199/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  22% (208/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  23% (218/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  24% (227/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  25% (236/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  26% (246/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  27% (255/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  28% (265/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  29% (274/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  30% (284/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  31% (293/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  32% (303/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  33% (312/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  34% (321/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  35% (331/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  36% (340/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  37% (350/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  38% (359/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  39% (369/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  40% (378/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  41% (388/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  42% (397/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  43% (406/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  44% (416/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  45% (425/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  46% (435/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  47% (444/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  48% (454/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  49% (463/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  50% (472/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  51% (482/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  52% (491/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  53% (501/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  54% (510/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  55% (520/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  56% (529/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  57% (539/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  58% (548/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  59% (557/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  60% (567/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  61% (576/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  62% (586/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  63% (595/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  64% (605/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  65% (614/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  66% (624/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  67% (633/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  68% (642/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  69% (652/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  70% (661/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  71% (671/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  72% (680/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  73% (690/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  74% (699/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  75% (708/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  76% (718/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  77% (727/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  78% (737/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  79% (746/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  80% (756/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  81% (765/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  82% (775/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  83% (784/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  84% (793/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  85% (803/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  86% (812/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  87% (822/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  88% (831/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  89% (841/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  90% (850/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  91% (860/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  92% (869/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  93% (878/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  94% (888/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  95% (897/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  96% (907/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  97% (916/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  98% (926/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects:  99% (935/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (944/944)        
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (944/944), done.        
  Receiving objects:   0% (1/1694)
  Receiving objects:   1% (17/1694)
  Receiving objects:   2% (34/1694)
  Receiving objects:   3% (51/1694)
  Receiving objects:   4% (68/1694)
  Receiving objects:   5% (85/1694)
  Receiving objects:   6% (102/1694)
  Receiving objects:   7% (119/1694)
  Receiving objects:   8% (136/1694)
  Receiving objects:   9% (153/1694)
  Receiving objects:  10% (170/1694)
  Receiving objects:  11% (187/1694)
  Receiving objects:  12% (204/1694)
  Receiving objects:  13% (221/1694)
  Receiving objects:  14% (238/1694)
  Receiving objects:  15% (255/1694)
  Receiving objects:  16% (272/1694)
  Receiving objects:  17% (288/1694)
  Receiving objects:  18% (305/1694)
  Receiving objects:  19% (322/1694)
  Receiving objects:  20% (339/1694)
  Receiving objects:  21% (356/1694)
  Receiving objects:  22% (373/1694)
  Receiving objects:  23% (390/1694)
  Receiving objects:  24% (407/1694)
  Receiving objects:  25% (424/1694)
  Receiving objects:  26% (441/1694)
  Receiving objects:  27% (458/1694)
  Receiving objects:  28% (475/1694)
  Receiving objects:  29% (492/1694)
  Receiving objects:  30% (509/1694)
  Receiving objects:  31% (526/1694)
  Receiving objects:  32% (543/1694)
  Receiving objects:  33% (560/1694)
  Receiving objects:  34% (576/1694)
  Receiving objects:  35% (593/1694)
  Receiving objects:  36% (610/1694)
  Receiving objects:  37% (627/1694)
  Receiving objects:  38% (644/1694)
  Receiving objects:  39% (661/1694)
  Receiving objects:  40% (678/1694)
  Receiving objects:  41% (695/1694)
  Receiving objects:  42% (712/1694)
  Receiving objects:  43% (729/1694)
  Receiving objects:  44% (746/1694)
  Receiving objects:  45% (763/1694)
  Receiving objects:  46% (780/1694)
  Receiving objects:  47% (797/1694)
  Receiving objects:  48% (814/1694)
  Receiving objects:  49% (831/1694)
  Receiving objects:  50% (847/1694)
  Receiving objects:  51% (864/1694)
  Receiving objects:  52% (881/1694)
  Receiving objects:  53% (898/1694)
  Receiving objects:  54% (915/1694)
  Receiving objects:  55% (932/1694)
  Receiving objects:  56% (949/1694)
  Receiving objects:  57% (966/1694)
  Receiving objects:  58% (983/1694)
  Receiving objects:  59% (1000/1694)
  Receiving objects:  60% (1017/1694)
  Receiving objects:  61% (1034/1694)
  Receiving objects:  62% (1051/1694)
  Receiving objects:  63% (1068/1694)
  Receiving objects:  64% (1085/1694)
  Receiving objects:  65% (1102/1694)
  Receiving objects:  66% (1119/1694)
  Receiving objects:  67% (1135/1694)
  Receiving objects:  68% (1152/1694)
  Receiving objects:  69% (1169/1694)
  Receiving objects:  70% (1186/1694)
  Receiving objects:  71% (1203/1694)
  Receiving objects:  72% (1220/1694)
  Receiving objects:  73% (1237/1694)
  Receiving objects:  74% (1254/1694)
  Receiving objects:  75% (1271/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  76% (1288/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  77% (1305/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  78% (1322/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  79% (1339/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  80% (1356/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  81% (1373/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  82% (1390/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  83% (1407/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  84% (1423/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  85% (1440/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  86% (1457/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  87% (1474/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  88% (1491/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  89% (1508/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  remote: Total 1694 (delta 779), reused 1448 (delta 694), pack-reused 0        
  Receiving objects:  90% (1525/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  91% (1542/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  92% (1559/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  93% (1576/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Receiving objects:  94% (1593/1694), 324.01 KiB | 640.00 KiB/s
  Rec<message truncated>
```

I never install cocoa pods but it worked before.
Okey, I try search problem in google, I tried
$ gem uninstall cocoapods
$ gem install cocoapods

Uninstall good, but install error:

```
Successfully uninstalled cocoapods-1.8.4
Mac-MacBook-Pro:~ mac$ sudo gem install cocoapods
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/ext/ffi_c
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20220607-2280-91gmgf.rb extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-ffi_c-dir
    --without-ffi_c-dir
    --with-ffi_c-include
    --without-ffi_c-include=${ffi_c-dir}/include
    --with-ffi_c-lib
    --without-ffi_c-lib=${ffi_c-dir}/lib
    --enable-system-libffi
    --disable-system-libffi
    --with-libffi-config
    --without-libffi-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `block in try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:534:in `with_werror'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:585:in `try_compile'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1109:in `block in have_header'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1108:in `have_header'
    from extconf.rb:10:in `system_libffi_usable?'
    from extconf.rb:42:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-20/2.6.0/ffi-1.15.5/gem_make.out
```

Okey, I try find solution in google.
I try this:
brew cleanup -d -v

result:
-bash: brew: command not found

So.. I don't know what is cocoa pods what is brew or etc., i will delete everything and reinstall it.
Before I only install unity and Xcode, I added firebase to unity project and I've never had a problem with this before..

What is the problem now?
And what is the solution?
I think I don't need what I'm doing because I haven't needed it before..

I don't understand why i have to install cocoa pods and brew and etc. that have never been needed before. (I think installed automatically with Xcode or unity, I don't remember I used terminal ever.. I used terminal only for firebase functions..)

Thanks,
Adrian

Edit:
I tried to open my old game (which has never been a this problem). I think maybe problem with new version Firebase and that older version maybe good. But an error message appeared immediately when I open.. maybe when I tried uninstall cocoa pods..
[image]

Edit 08 Jun 18:12:

I tried install cocoa pods again, succesfully installed 1.8.4.

I read this:

> > Depending on some aspects this might work for you, if you don't mind using the "SUDO" command:
>
> sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods -v 1.8.4
>
> Latest CocoaPods 1.10.0 won't work.

I find it here: [apple developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/668456)

Okey I have 1.8.4.

But "[!] `FirebaseAnalytics` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.10.0`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.8.4`."

So I try many solution what I find in google.

- I installed home-brew
  (for install home-brew I installed Xcode developer tools in terminal, and tried many possible solution, example sudo gem update, sudo brew update, gem install, sudo gem install cocoapods, so everything..)

not working.
I can't update cocoa pods.

I tried this:
gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.1
(because that is need for firebase.)

nothing.
I uninstall whole Xcode and reinstall. maybe.
nothing.

So.
One question.

I can't install cocoapods new version in macOS Big Sur 11.6.6?
(This is my last update in my 2014 Mid MacBook Pro)

anyone have any ideas?
I swear i pay for it if someone does it because i give up.

thanks....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939568/error-error-installing-cocoapods-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension

Comment: this solution worked for me for m1 Mac https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73295639/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-firebase-unity-xcode

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:**

Check if CocoaPods is installed by entering the `pod` command on the terminal. if pod installation is successful then go to the next step else
try to install the pod first. This [link](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#getting-started) will help you default installation process. If that also fails, try to install the pod with the help of [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/cocoapods).

**Step2:**

Make sure your pod repo is updated.
Try `pod setup` and `pod repo update`

**Step3:**

Check the pod location by `which pod`.
If you are using homebrew then the location will be `/opt/homebrew/bin/pod`
else `/usr/local/bin/pod`. You can check which one is used by Unity by clicking ***Assets->External Dependency Manager->iOS Resolver->install cocoapods***. The iOS resolver popup will show the location. If it is not able to find the cocoa pod installation then **repeat** *steps 1 and 2*.

**Step4:**

Make the Xcode build, if it is successful go to the folder and check if there is any file with the name ***Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace*** then your life has been saved. Sometimes unity throw this error even if it has generated the workspace.

**Step5:**

If the workspace file has not been generated go to the folder where the build has been generated and make sure it contains file ***Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj***.
open the folder in the terminal and enter `pod install` command wait a bit it will generate the ***Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace*** file .[image] Double click the file and open the project in Xcode you will able to see your generated pod files under the pods folder in the Xcode folder view on the left side.

Useful links:

1. [Unity Thread.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-framework-addition-failed-due-to-a-cocoapods-installation-failure.483511/)
2. [Other Link.](http://shobhitsamaria.com/cocoapods-installation-failure-while-building-unity-project-for-ios/)

Comment: really nice solution, because it helps understanding the fundamental problem behind it, tks, it helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

I strugled with it for 3 last days in Unity AND XCode... Only solution I've found was downgrading it to version 8.15.0, this error happens only if I tried to use version 9+. Did google screwed something with repository?

Comment: Firebase 8.15.0 or what?

Answer (score 0):

although I'm not finish my question, maybe you can check this
[this](https://www.jianshu.com/p/30f9214244a1)

I just follow it's steps and there are no errors after build xcode project

And I just keep finding other solution for

> 'GoogleSignIn/GIDSignIn.h' file not found

If anyone has suggestion or answer about that question, just share it plz

Good luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Have you upgraded OSX since you last ran the successful build?
This is an OSX issue with the default ruby installed by big sur and not so much a Unity or Plugin issue. If you try running the commands in the terminal you will encounter the same issue outside of Unity.

your options are:

1. to upgrade OSX and therefore upgrade the system ruby
2. update ruby and follow this guide as a new version via rvm wont automatically override the system default https://gist.github.com/RedenticDev/2c71869492ba2740a3725216898c522a

related to : [Failed to Install CocoaPods in Unity LTS 2017.4.40f1 and Appodeal on mac os x Mojave 10.14.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72476760/failed-to-install-cocoapods-in-unity-lts-2017-4-40f1-and-appodeal-on-mac-os-x-mo/73550437#73550437)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution for this, in my case it was that when i installed the unity package of firebase.analytics, i installed an upgraded version (in my case 10.0.1), but i had to install exactly the same version that corresponded to the firebase package(in my case 9.5.0), so, every firebase plugin must have the exact version number.

So i had to basically downgrade specifically the firebase analytics package with help of this page https://developers.google.com/unity/archive#google_analytics_for_firebase and find the corresponding one.

IMPORTANT: You have to erase the previous version u had on the project before importing the correct version, an easy way to do this is double clicking on the new unity package you download, and check which folders and archives are conflicting with your project, and deleting them